# Allowing zooming when point range is less than [-1,1] in DataVisualization.Charting?

Tags: .net, charts, data-visualization

I have a DataVisualization.Charting.Chart and in order to enable user controlled zooming I have set

```
        chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chartArea1.CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chartArea1.CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
```

However, if I make a series that has an axis along which the range of the data is within [-1,1] the chart will not allow zooming on that axis. Is there a way to enable zooming?

Also the zooming selector seems quite chunky (it snaps to major intervals or something) is it possible to get smoother selection?

Comment: It this using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: sorry for taking long to respond, I am doing this WinForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused by the zooming cursor only being able to take position coordinates on a discrete grid. These are controled by Cursor.Interval and Cursor.Offset. You can change this by setting

```
Chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
Chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.Interval = 0;
```

This makes the grid continuous so the zooming cursor can take any coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Covering both *WPF* and *WinForms* as you did not specify in your question.

**WPF**

<s>It sounds like that the chart is virtualizing the contents (i.e. only drawing what is in view). You probably verify if this is the case by setting `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` to `False`. You will want to keep the virtualizng on as otherwise performance will suffer with a large data set.</s>

**WinForms**

Have you set the `Chart.DoubleBuffered` property? Setting this property to `true` will make the chart control redraw its surface using a secondary buffer to reduce or prevent flicker.

- `Chart` Class ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx))
- `Control.DoubleBuffered` Property ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx))

Comment: Thank you, I have not set it and I will try it on tuesday. Why would a secondary buffer allow zooming? I don't grok.

Comment: I believe the problem you are seeing is simply rendering redraw (i.e. flickering) which would be fixed by double buffering the paint. ... It is just a good guess at the issue without creating a sample application and debugging it myself.

Comment: it turns out that the Control.DoubleBuffered is protected, so you cannot modify it from outside. Also, I do not see how lack of the double buffered value would prevent you from even drawing the zooming rectangle.

Comment: Yes, it is protected and to access it you need to Subclass the `Chart` control. Even though you have *fixed* your problem you will probably still see better performance by setting the control to be double buffered.